# C++ - Database schema using migration

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm working on an application that requires the use of a database. We are currently using migration files, however, this is just raw sql and can get quite messy and confusing, especially with everyone adding to it and also keeping it up to date is becoming a lot harder.

I have been contemplating the idea of having a migration type functionality into the application, where we create a class for each of the migrations and then define the table and columns etc.. Using lambdas. However, what I've come up with does not seem to be working. Here is an example so far:

```
class Schema {
     public:

          Schema() { } // construct 

          template<typename T>
          void static create(std::string name, T t)
          {
               cout << "Create is started.."; 
               // This is where all the logic will go 
          } 

          void static integer(std::string column_name)
          { 
              std::cout << "Column integer is called";
              // put SQL here for integer value
          }
};
```

Then the migration file will work something like:

```
class CreateUserTable {

    public:
       CreateUserTable() {

            Schema::create("users", []()
            {
                Schema::integer("id");
            }); 
       }


};
```

The idea is that when I call these migration files, essentially it will produce a series of well formed sql statements that I can use for my migrations.

The question:

With using Lambdas (as it is), how would I go about calling each of the function calls for the columns before the create function is executed fully?

EDIT:

To clear things up, essentially, in the body of the lambda function, whenever I call:

```
Schema::integer("COLUM_NAME");
```

It will add another layer to the final SQL statement. So let's say I did the following:

```
Schema::create("users", []()
{
      Schema::integer("id");
      Schema::integer("number"); 
});
```

It would create the following string:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  number INT NOT NOW AUTO_INCREMENT

)
```

But, by creating a new object of "CreateUserTable" the only thing that is outputted is: `cout << "Create is started..";` whereas I need `std::cout << "Column integer is called";` to be called before it.. It doesn't look like it's doing anything with the function?

Comment: @erip - I have updated my question -- Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: By the way, is there any particular reason you're using `static` methods?

Comment: @erip - Nope. This is just something I put together on the way home this evening. I just wanted to make sure that what I'm trying to do is possible, before starting to fully design it! I will most likely go down the none static methods since not needed in this instance.

Comment: Well it makes sense that you're seeing `"Create is started.."` first - it's the first thing that happens in your `create` method.

Comment: @erip - I understand this, it makes sense why it's showing `"Create is started.." I just can't seem to figure out why the `"Column integer is being called" isn't being called.. Because I'm pretty sure it should work!

Comment: You're passing `T t` to `create`, but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: @erip - Sorry! So what would `T t` have? I don't quite understand what I can do with it? I can't call `t.integer()` Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is why `static` isn't good for this design.

Comment: See listing 9 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/howto-use-lambda-exp-cpp11-2189895.html) for how to pass a lambda to a function.

Comment: @erip - Got it! Makes sense, although, I think that the `::` looks better than creating an object and using `.` or `->`! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the lambda to actually perform task

```
class Schema {
     public:

          Schema() { } // construct 

          template<typename T>
          void static create(std::string name, T const & t) // pass reference to avoid copy
          {
               cout << "Create is started.."; 
               t(); // call the lambda to do the actual work
               cout << "Create is ended."; // you can run generated sql query now
          } 

          void static integer(std::string column_name)
          { 
              std::cout << "Column integer is called";
              // put SQL here for integer value
          }
};
```

Just be aware that this code is not thread-safe. If multiple `Schema::create` get called at same time, you will have unexpected result. You can pass a schema builder object to the lambda and use it to build the query to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, I will suggest you used the builder pattern to build your sql statement it will be easily ;
Your code should look something like this

```
class Schama{
    public:
    static void create(std::string table, void (*callback)(Builder &*builder)){
             
        //then use the builder class to build your class
        Builder *builder = new Builder(table);
        if(callback)callback(builder)
           if(builder)
          {
             Table *table = builder->build();
             table->create();
          }
    }
    Scheme::drop(std::string tablename){/* build your delete statement
    }
};
```

The Builder class can then have the follow

```
class Builder
{
   public:
       Builder * String(std::string);
       Builder  *Integer(std::string);
       Builder  *Primary(std::string);
       Builder  *Auto();
       Builder  *Foreign(std::string parent, std::string colname);
       Builder  *Unique();
       Builder   *Blob(std::string columname)
       Table     *  build();
};
```

code here

This is how laravel framework schema class handles it and it's quite simple and easy to use.

Comment: thanks for this. Can you please edit your post so that the code is within tags! Also, how would I call this?